# ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error after I had a Windows update today my Oracle database doesn't start any more

Tags: ora-12560

When I connect with SQL*Plus I get:

ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2846]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>LSNRCTL.EXE start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 24-APR-2023 13:11:32

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started

C:\Windows\system32>